# PHP submit form not working

Tags: php, submit

Below is a piece of the code that input the results of a query into radio buttons. Then, when the user pushes one of the buttons in the form, it moves to the pages test.php. I have run into a problem though that the second code (which is on test.php) doesn't seem to work although I can't see any reason that it shouldn't. Any ideas are awesome. Thanks.

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="server" value="<?php echo $row['serverId']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['dateCreated']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverId']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['publicDNS'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['isRunning']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<br>
<?php endif; ?>

<form method="post" name="server_information" id="server_information" action="test.php">
<input type="submit" name="server_stop" value="Stop Server"/>
<input type="submit" name="server_terminate" value="Terminate Server"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Second Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['server_stop'])) {
    echo "Server Stopped";
}

if (isset($_POST['server_terminate'])) {
    echo "Server Terminated"
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['submit']` has to be `$_POST['server_stop']`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['server_stop'])) {
    echo "Server Stopped";
}

if (isset($_POST['server_terminate'])) {
    echo "Server Terminated";
}

?>
```

Comment: I updated the code, but it still does not display what is inside the echo statements. Any other ideas?

Comment: I edited the code, try again. I Changed `echo "Server Terminated"` to `echo "Server Terminated";`

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I missed that semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['server_stop'])) {
    echo "Server Stopped";
}

if (isset($_POST['server_terminate'])) {
    echo "Server Terminated"
}

?>
```

Both of these conditions are true on form submit. If you want to differentiate between which submit button was pressed, you'll need to make a hidden input and use some javascript:

```
<form method="post" name="server_information" id="server_information" action="test.php">
<input type="submit" name="server_stop" value="Stop Server" onclick="whatwasclicked(this);" />
<input type="submit" name="server_terminate" value="Terminate Server" onclick="whatwasclicked(this);" />
<input type="hidden" name="clicked" id="clicked" />
</form>
```

Your javascript will be:

```
function whatwasclicked(c) {
$("#clicked").val() = c.value;
}
```

Now on the PHP side, you'll check `$_POST['clicked']` and see which button was pressed.

EDIT:
Be aware there is Jquery being used here... so be sure to load that library.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript at all, and you're only going to have those submit buttons in the form, you could also do this:

```
<form method="post" name="server_information" id="server_information" action="test.php">
<input type="submit" name="clicked" value="Stop Server"/>
</form>
<form method="post" name="server_information" id="server_information" action="test.php">
<input type="submit" name="clicked" value="Terminate Server"/>
</form>
```

Now just check for `$_POST['clicked']` and you'll see which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name =trim($_POST['name']);
  if (empty($name)){
    echo "please input name";    
  }
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)){
    $namerr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
  }
}
```

Comment: elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
  $namerr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}